# FuelSDK Endpoints Clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#, python

I can authenticate the REST API through Postman, but I've tried both the python FuelSDK and C# SDK but I can't seem to get either of them to connect to my instance of Marketing Cloud. I think I'm just getting the endpoints wrong.

### Installed Packages

This is what my installed packages look like:
[image: Installed Packages]

### Postman

Postman seems to work, when I send the following request to `https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token`

```json
{ "grant_type": "client_credentials"
, "client_id": "..."
, "client_secret": "..."
, "scope": "data_extensions_read data_extensions_write"
, "account_id": "..." }
```

The response is:

```json
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 1079,
    "scope": "data_extensions_read data_extensions_write",
    "soap_instance_url": "https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/",
    "rest_instance_url": "https://blah.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"
}
```

So I think postman works.

### C# FuelSDK

However not in C#. I installed v1.1.1 of the FuelSDK through NuGet. When I try running the following code in C#:

```C#
var client = new ETClient(new NameValueCollection {
    { "clientId", "CLIENTID" },
    { "clientSecret", "SECRET" },
    { "authEndPoint", "https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token" },
    { "soapEndPoint", "https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/" },
    { "restEndPoint", "https://blah.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/" },
});
```

I get an exception on that line:

> System.Net.WebException
>   "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

When I change the `authEndPoint` to `https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/` I get:

> "The remote server returned an error: (596) ."

When I remove `authEndPoint` all together I get:

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

### Python FuelSDK

My `~/.fuelsdk/config.python` looks like this:

```sh
[Web Services]
appsignature: none
clientid: CLIENTID
clientsecret: CLIENTSECRET
defaultwsdl: https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/ETFramework.wsdl
baseapiurl: https://www.marketingcloudapis.com
authenticationurl: https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token
soapendpoint: https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/
wsdl_file_local_loc: /tmp/ExactTargetWSDL.s6.xml
```

When I run the following code:

```python
client = FuelSDK.ET_Client()
```

I get the following error:

```json
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided:
{
'error': 'unsupported_grant_type',
'error_description': 'Use "authorization_code" or "refresh_token" or "client_credentials" or "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" as the grant_type.',
'error_uri': 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs'
}
```

When I change `authenticationurl` to `https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/` 
I get the following exception:

```python
...
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I remove `authenticationurl`, I get the following exception:

```python
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {'message': 'Unauthorized', 'errorcode': 1, 'documentation': ''}
```

I'm at wit's end, does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and i looked at client.py. Looks like it was setup only to handle v1/requestToken and not v2/token. So i tried to edit the client.py to make sure the grant_type and client_id and client_secret is passed over then hand to change the response variables it was parsing. Even after all that my response was 
Post response:False
Code: HTTPStatus.OK
Message: Error: API Permission Failed.
Result Count: 0
Results: []

Comment: Sadly I think you're right, I ended up downloading the source code, and it was too out of date I didn't know where to start...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. FuelPHP seems to be outdated and full of bugs, so I'm sending my requests directly with CURL...

Here's a working example:

```
    $server = "https://blablabla.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
$json = json_encode(array('client_id' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID','client_secret' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET','grant_type' => 'client_credentials'));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('POST / HTTP/1.1','Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: '.strlen($json)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($raw, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The C# Fuel SDK has been updated to handle the new oAuth 2.0 process

Answer (score 0):

Try these? It works for me

1. When you instantiate the client, declare 'useOAuth2Authentication' as 'True'
2. Remove v2/token from the authentication url

Like this in Python

```
stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(
  False, False,
  {
      'clientid': '<CLIENT_ID>',
      'clientsecret': '<CLIENT_SECRET>',
      'defaultwsdl': 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
      'authenticationurl': 'https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
      'baseapiurl': '<REST TENANT SPECIFIC ENDPOINT>',
      'soapendpoint': '<SOAP TENANT SPECIFIC ENDPOINT>',
      'wsdl_file_local_loc': r'<WSDL_PATH>/ExactTargetWSDL.xml',
      'useOAuth2Authentication': 'True',
      'accountId': '<TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID>',
      'scope': '<PERMISSION_LIST>'
  })
```